# Changing Json return format of Spring OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

while consolidating our json responses, I tried to change the spring oauth2 json response to our format.

From

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Invalid access token: undefined"
}
```

To

```
{
  "status" : 401,
  "error_code": "invalid_token",
  "description": "Invalid access token: undefined"
}
```

I've debugged and found several points which probably relevant, but I have trouble bring everything together.

These were my approaches

- The response is written here `OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Serializer`, but I don't know how to exchange that serializer within spring
- I found the `WebResponseExceptionTranslator`. But from my understanding, it doesn't allow to set a json body there
- The json body is written by DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer, but I couldn't manage to set that. I only found how to set the `ExceptionTranslator`, by setting it in `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`. But it doesn't allow to set the renderer
- The documentation talks about setting an `HttpMessageConverter`, I didn't figure out how to do that.

Long story short, I'm new to Spring and I really would appreciate some guidance on how to modify the repsonse.

Thanks, 
Otto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, register the WebResponseExceptionTranslator:

```
    @Bean
public WebResponseExceptionTranslator webResponseExceptionTranslator() {
    return new DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator() {
        @Override
        public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> translate(Exception e) throws Exception {
            ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> responseEntity = super.translate(e);
            OAuth2Exception body = responseEntity.getBody();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAll(responseEntity.getHeaders().toSingleValueMap());

           // translate the exception

            return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It did not trigger when the oauth server return invalid_token status